# Can Rails' POW work offline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, pow

Even though my server is exclusively located on my local box, if I'm not connected to an actual internet connection, I get each browser's "Check your Internet Connection" or "No Connection" messages.

Is there a way to bypass this? I've noticed in the latest upgrade of POW, if I were to restart my computer, I'd have to type :

```
sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
sudo pfctl -e
```

But that doesn't seem to help in this situation. Any tips would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- can you curl/wget your local server?
- is it running in development mode (locahost:3000)?
- do you see log output from your local server when performing curl or wget?

if yes, try to switch the browser to offline mode ('Work Offline' from the file menu or something like this.

Comment: Yah it seems curl doesn't work. Can't seem to turn Chrome into Work Offline. The server is running, but it doesn't use localhost:3000, it uses 9292 with POW (http://pow.cx/)